# PHP adding quotes to DB output

Tags: php

In the DB is a value `Qu'est-ce qu'un`, when this is output on the page it comes out as `Qu''est-ce qu''un` - an extra quote is added each time.

Anyone know what causes this? Magic_quotes is ON but I don't think it's related.

Comment: And how are you getting the value from the db?

Comment: And how do you output it to the page? You've asked 127 other questions so far and you still don't know that we *need to see your code*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems related to [magic_quotes_runtime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-runtime) (and magic_quotes_sybase) setting in php.ini

Answer (score 0):

It is related to magic_quotes, [`stripslashes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) should remove the extra `'`:

> If magic_quotes_sybase is on, no backslashes are stripped off but two apostrophes are replaced by one instead.